# Is "Friends, Romans, ..." a historical speech?

Tags: roman-republic, literature, quotes

While searching for a canonical translation to my language of the phrase [Friends, Romans, countrymen, lend me your ears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friends,_Romans,_countrymen,_lend_me_your_ears) I was surprised to find reference to it only in the Shakespeare play. As the play is based on historical events, was this a true historical quote or were the words concocted in the 16th century?

My intuition tells me that since the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friends,_Romans,_countrymen,_lend_me_your_ears) for the play does not have the words in Latin, that it is in fact *not* an historical quote. Is it?

Addendum: Since I'm *not sure* if this is a historical quote, it is off topic to ask about it here? If so, is there a better SE site to have asked on?

Comment: Appian recorded Mark Anthony's funeral oration in his Civil Wars books. No idea how accurate Shakespeare's version is (or even if it's based on Appian's).

Comment: @YannisRizos: Thank you, I'm off to research that.

Comment: I'm having a little bit of a hard time with the question. It is asking if someone who wrote works of fiction, in a iambic pentameter, in Elizabethan English, copied a speech from a long time before, in a completely different language, by people who had no reason to force their words into any rhyming scheme. How could that be possible? It's kind of like saying "Did the Pokemon's use John F Kennedy's inaugural address as the basis of their story"

Comment: One exception to your statement - fine oratory has **always** been about developing a rhythm with the words that strikes a resonance with the audience. While Mark Antony certainly did not deliver his funeral oration in English iambic pentameter, he almost certainly *did* deliver it in a poetic fashion.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, Dan, I actually do appreciate your criticism. Considering the the historical event was the basis of the fictional work, and considering the popularity of the quote and it's association with the historical figure, I found it prudent to know if the quote was attributed to the right place.

Comment: Standard practice for ancient historians is to put words into the mouths of their characters in order to summarize or dramatize particular situations. Its rare for the quotes to be what we'd consider verbatim, although sometimes memorable phrases ("Carthage must be destroyed", "You too, Brutus") are presumptively word for word.  There are verbatim speeches, usually from law courts or formal debates (Cicero & Demosthenes are examples) but pretty much all impromptu speeches or battlefield exhortations are somewhere between a paraphrase and a history channel voice-over.

Comment: @theodox: I suspected as much, but the idea of opening with such a greeting is creatively effective. It creates instant rapport with the audience. I wondered if this building of rapport in fact is factual, not necessarily word-for-word translation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

@YannisRizos answered the question.

> It is not known what he said, but the result was that the Roman masses became very angry with Caesar's murderers, burnt down their houses and made them flee from he city. *[Livius](http://www.livius.org/caa-can/caesar/caesar_t14.html)*

[Appian's transcript of Mark Anthony's funeral oration](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Appian/Civil_Wars/3%2a.html), suggests that Shakespeare wrote for the stage, not for historical accuracy (although this is a record of what was said, not a transcript).

Comment: Hey, unique opportunity to upvote myself! Thanks for taking the time to convert my comment to a proper answer.

Comment: I dunno, I feel guilty, like I'm a parasite on your rep.  I owe you.

Comment: @YannisRizos: I had actually waited a bit to see if you would answer. When the question became a popular question I figured that I better select Mark's answer (and he provided a great link). Go ahead and answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Don't worry about it. I was hoping someone would find the time to find some proper sources for my comment, good thing you did. I'm here for the answers, couldn't care less for the rep.